# Unable to access data in shared memory created from 1 script to other script

Tags: python, scripting, shared-memory

I have two scripts one script is creating a space in shared memory and adding data in that shared memory other script is accessing the data in that memory. But I'm receiving error
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/psm_db77e072'`

script1.py

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory


shm_a = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='psm_db77e072', create=True, size=10)
print(shm_a.name)
buffer = shm_a.buf
buffer[:4] = bytearray([22, 33, 44, 55])  # Modify multiple at once
buffer[4] = 100
```

script2.py

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import array

shm_name = 'psm_db77e072'  # Replace with the actual name from the first script
shm_b = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)

data_array = array.array('b', shm_b.buf[:5])
print(data_array)
```

Comment: When script1.py ends, the shared memory segment will have been lost. You have to be very careful with shared memory in Python in terms of closing and unlinking